# What is the size of 1 minute video at 1920 x 1080 (60 fps)?

Tags: file-formats, video-recording, mpeg, avchd, formats

I would like to know what is the size in MB for 1 minute video captured in the following format:

1920 x 1080 (60 fps) AVCHD

and

1920 x 1080 (60 fps) MPEG-4

with peak data rate of 24Mbit/sec

How to calculate it?

Comment: You need to know the average bitrate instead of the peak bit rate. Than you pretty much only need to do the math.

Comment: Also note that the codec, container, even the frame dimensions make no difference in the calculation: average or constant bits per second times the number of seconds determines the file size without regard to any other factor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try those calculators, they should do the trick.

http://www.digitalrebellion.com/webapps/videocalc